# home screen icon

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I just updated my Sencha Touch to Sencha Touch 2.0.1 and my home screen icon is no longer working. Previously I could inspect my code and see the correct `<link>` tags generated by Sencha. I no longer see these tags. I have my home screen icon set up with the following code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'example',
    phoneIcon: '/example/resources/icons/app_icons/114x114.png',
```

I have also tried changing "phoneIcon" to "icon", and I have also tried using an object after "icon" instead of a string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `icon` property works fine for me:

[image: Screenshot]

Example application: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#f15tv